# Improve procedure in assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, factorial, irvine32

I want to write a factorial procedure passing through parameter. Please help. Help me see if this code needs improvement like how to make this code shorter and simpler. It is way too long, I just want the main function.

```
 INCLUDELIB C:\Irvine\Kernel32.lib
 INCLUDELIB C:\Irvine\Irvine32.lib
 INCLUDE C:\Irvine\Irvine32.inc

 .code
 main PROC
     push 5             ; calc 5!
     call Factorial     ; calculate factorial (EAX)
     call WriteDec      ; display it
     call Crlf
     exit
 main ENDP

 ;----------------------------------------------------------
 Factorial PROC
 ; Calculates a factorial.
 ; Receives: [ebp+8] = n, the number to calculate
 ; Returns: eax = the factorial of n
 ;----------------------------------------------------------
 push ebp
 mov ebp,esp
 mov eax,[ebp+8]     ; get n
 cmp eax,0                 ; n > 0?
 ja L1                ; yes: continue
 mov eax,1                 ; no: return 1 as the value of 0!
 jmp L2               ; and return to the caller

 L1: dec  eax             ; Factorial(n-1)
 push eax
 call Factorial

; Instructions from this point on execute when each
; recursive call returns.

 ReturnFact:
 mov ebx,[ebp+8]     ; get n
 mul ebx              ; EDX:EAX = EAX * EBX

 L2: pop ebp         ; return EAX
 ret 4                ; clean up stack
 Factorial ENDP
 END main
```

Comment: Considering that 12! is the largest you can calculate with 32 bit registers, you could just do a single index into a 12 entry table. You could also index into a 12 entry branch table into an unfolded loop that does multiplies, or you could loop up to 12 times.

Comment: can you please me write me an answer, i"m so lost. I promise I will accept it as the answer! I just need to know how to write in nonrecursive!

Comment: I take it this is for a homework assignment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be asking for help on a homework assignment without showing attempts made and specific difficulties as outlined in [paragraph 3 of the online help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

This will do an extra multiply by 1, but it's short.

```
factorial proc  near
        mov     ecx,[esp+4]
        mov     eax,1
        cmp     ecx,eax
        jb      fct1
fct0:   mul     ecx
        loop    fct0
fct1:   ret
factorial endp
```

Answer (score 0):

Next is the full program for the non-recursive factorial using loop instruction, just copy, paste and run (made with EMU8086) :

```
.stack 100h
.data
my_factor dw 5
.code          
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax,@data
  mov  ds,ax

  push my_factor  
  call non_recursive_factorial

;FINISH PROGRAM PROPERLY.  
  mov  ax,4c00h
  int  21h           

proc non_recursive_factorial
  pop  ax         ;EXTRACT THE ADDRESS TO RETURN TO CALL.
  pop  my_factor  ;EXTRACT THE PARAMETER (THE FACTOR).
  push ax         ;PUT BACK THE ADDRESS TO RETURN TO CALL.
  mov  ax,my_factor
  mov  cx,my_factor
  dec  cx            
while:                                  
  mul  cx ;AX*CX = DX:AX.
  loop while
  ret
endp
```